# Internet Forwarding

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, internet, gateway, ip-forwarding

I am looking for Internet Routing. Right now we have 2 offices one in Germany and One in Dubai. Everyone is connected through VPN Tunnel of the German office. The German office wants to connect to our Dubai Office but we don't have a VPN Tunnel or Static IP since it's very hard to obtain a static IP.

What are the options? Since

10.0.0.2 is. German office and
10.0.0.3 is a Dubai office is it possible by any way to make a Internet forwarding?

Comment: You can establish the site-to-site VPN from Dubai to a VPN server in the German office. Once the tunnel (from Dubai to Germany) is established it can and should be configured to route traffic in both directions, you don’t need a separate VPN tunnel going the other way I.e. from Germany to Dubai.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague in terminology. I am trying to understand what you are looking for:  you are looking for options to connect your 2 office locations in Germany and Dubai via a VPN or similar service. In your current setup you have a LAN in Dubai and a LAN in Germany but every user in Dubai is building its own Client VPN connection to the German office. Your question is whether you can simplify that setup by switching to a site-to-site VPN solution so all devices in the Dubai network can connect to the devices in the German network and vice versa. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I am looking for that. We have access to German Internet. Since it's a pfsense VPN Connection. Now the problem is German office which is inside the vpn network wants to have access to the Dubai offices Internet. We are using Pfsense in Germany and ZTE 680 in Dubai Office we can develop a vm pfsense but I need help on your to develop a connection if it's Site to Site on pfsense.

Comment: Please note Dubai office dosent have a Static or Public IP